# How to return primitive data types in a Django Rest Framework response (and not a UUID)

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'd like to know how to return primitive data types in a response in `Django Rest Framework`,(especially for `UUID`'s, to return them as a `string`).

I have this code:

```
class TicketCreateSerializer(BaseCreateSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = TICKET_FIELDS

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        obj = super(TicketCreateSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
        return dict(obj)
```

It is returning:

```
{
    'requester': UUID('e1ba1b8b-5d9b-473e-947b-971d795e9137'),
    'attachments': [],
    'assignee': UUID('f584c3cb-2c9d-4a26-8e59-1dd343839606'),
    'id': '00aa5549-f701-4b7e-82a5-5b2ac48c96ae',
    'location': UUID('9f9e5b8d-b156-47d9-98fc-bbec10788040'),
    'status': UUID('8a7edad5-19bb-4708-8d50-58a516749734'),
    'cc': [UUID('e8fb8a4b-d79c-4601-b31e-5abdbe8dbfee')],
    'priority': UUID('3f3ba388-6652-4744-9804-5d7e041cee7f'),
    'request': 'new request name',
    'categories': [UUID('c88f3e94-3d35-4816-80fb-6188fa6ec280')]
}
```

Instead of UUID data types for the ID's, is there a simple built in way to return strings of the ID's instead? To do this in Django Rest Framework?

*Basically, how to return primitive python data types?*

I feel like I've solved this issue in the past, but can't remember how...

Comment: What do you want to use that for? This behavior is normal, as the serializer is only the first step. Next, serializer output is fed into a renderer (such as the `JSONRenderer`) to produce the final output.

Comment: @spectras I want this so I can compare `ForeignKeys` in the initial-data vs. the post-data, and if there has been a change, then I want to log the change.  But since the post-data is a UUID, each time I have to cast it as a sting `str(UUID)` in order to be able to compare them.

Comment: It seems a bit odd the initial data is not an `UUID` too then. Where does it come from? It would be more logical to compare the native value than the serialized value.

Comment: @spectras the initial-data IDs aren't UUIDs yet because it is a mock Json post that then get's converted to Python.  It's only after the database save that they are UUIDs.  Thanks

Comment: Well, then you have two options: either convert your mock Json post's id into a `UUID` as well (as easy as invoking `uuid.UUID(the_id)`) and compare the python objects, or go all the way to a JSON document and compare the strings. I would do the first, but if you want the second, just wait a bit I'm writing something.

Comment: @spectras the thing is, I think this functionality exists within `django-rest-framework` to return a primitive python dictionary of values... IDK ... maybe id doesn't though?!

Comment: It doesn't. Or more accurately, DRF considers `uuid.UUID` to be such a simple type, like I wrote below.

Answer (score 3):

The DRF serialization is a 2-step process.

1. The object is converted into a dict by a *serializer*, with simple types.
2. The dict is given to a *renderer* to generate a document.

The exact definition of “simple types” is a bit blurry. Basically, it is “whatever the renderers accepts”. For the `JSONRenderer`, that means:

- all basic python types
- `datetime.datetime` / `datetime.date` / `datetime.time` / `datetime.timedelta`
- `decimal.Decimal`
- `uuid.UUID`
- `QuerySet`
- Numpy arrays and array scalars
- Any dict-like or sequence-like object.

Usually, you will only deal with step 1, as step 2 is automatically handled by DRF's `Response`. DRF automatically selects a rendered based on the view's `renderer_classes` setting and the request's `Accept` header.

**Doing step 2 manually**

You would do this if you need to generate a document (for instance a JSON document) yourself for some reason, for instance for tests. All you need is invoke the renderer yourself:

```
from rest_framwork.renderers import JSONRenderer
json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
```

That gets you a whole json document as a `bytestring`. This is an atomic process though, it's whole document or nothing.

You could imagine creating a custom renderer that returns a dict with only string values, but that's way overkill for your purpose.